# differential coefficient of even and odd functions

Tags: integration

I would like to know whether the differential coefficient of even functions is always an odd function and vice versa. I found it true in the case of polynomial and trigonometric functions but I do not know whether it is true in general. I am trying to evaluate the integral of the form $$\int_{-a}^a f'(x)f(x)dx$$ where $f'(x)=\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}$. Is it zero?

Comment: The antiderivative of $f'(x) f(x) $ is $f(x)^2 / 2 + c$

Comment: Yes, it's true in general. It's a quick application of the chain rule: $\frac{d}{dx} f(-x) = - f'(-x)$.